# Чтение из датафрейма

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Здраствуйте, я новичок, помогите пожалуйста.

Вот мой код:

```
import pandas as pd

""" Чтение файла """

file = r"C:\si.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)

print(df)
print(df["OPEN"])
```

после вывода df все четко получается выводит как надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После вывода первого столбца выходит такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите плз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pd.read_csv(file)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) по умолчанию использует `,` в качестве разделителя столбцов. Поэтому вы прочитали все данные в единственный столбец.

Воспользуйтесь параметром `sep=";"`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";")
```

---

Ваш CSV файл на самом деле содержит единственный столбец - **обратите внимание на то, что все строки заключены в кавычки**:

```
"OPEN;HIGH;LOW;CLOSE"
"79428;80170;79428;80042"
"80040;80119;79906;80063"
"80062;80343;80011;80171"
```

Прочитать такой файл можно так:

```
from io import StringIO

filename = r"D:\download\si.csv"

with open(filename) as f:
     data = "\n".join([line.strip('"\n') for line in f])

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=";")
```

---

результат:

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]:
       OPEN   HIGH    LOW  CLOSE
0     79428  80170  79428  80042
1     80040  80119  79906  80063
2     80062  80343  80011  80171
3     80171  80298  80105  80123
4     80119  80245  80016  80095
...     ...    ...    ...    ...
1863  71381  71459  71371  71422
1864  71419  71443  71393  71437
1865  71435  71458  71425  71446
1866  71445  71448  71382  71396
1867  71396  71412  71390  71390

[1868 rows x 4 columns]

In [48]: df["OPEN"]
Out[48]:
0       79428
1       80040
2       80062
3       80171
4       80119
        ...
1863    71381
1864    71419
1865    71435
1866    71445
1867    71396
Name: OPEN, Length: 1868, dtype: int64
```

**NOTE:** но лучше все-таки исправить сам CSV

Comment: добрый день, попробывал, как вы сказали, не помогло

Comment: @КириллМаликов, `не помогло` - это значит вы получаете ту же ошибку??

Comment: Да, тоже самое всплавает в плане ошибки

Comment: @КириллМаликов, можете выложить ваш CSV файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: вот тут, https://yadi.sk/d/1F7Zfs-HCUSw4g

Comment: @КириллМаликов, интересно как вы его получили? По стандарту CSV - этот файл содержит __один__ столбец, из-за того, что все заключено в кавычки

Comment: Так я его сцепил с разделителем точка запятая, в самом файле

Comment: Проблема в неправильном экранировании при помощи символа `"`

Comment: Господа, всем вам большое спасибо, Вы меня наталкнули на мысль где ошибка, токачто нашел. Проблема была, как вы правильно заметили в самом файле, я просто сделал новый csv но уже не сцеплял, а просто сохранил с расширением csv точка запятая и все стало работать

Comment: @Nobody. в данном случае проблема в неправильно созданном CSV файле

Comment: Все готов, огромное спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в самом файле, не нужно сцеплять, а просто сохранить в формате csv с разделителем точка запятая

Comment: “Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.”